# Distinguish duplicate key from updated key

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, on-duplicate-key

I have a SQL query that creates an ID:

```
insert into category(related,text) values(?,?) 
on duplicate key update id=last_insert_id(id)
```

I then get my ID:

```
$id=$connect->lastinsertid()
```

Is there a way to distinguish between an ID that was found as a duplicate and one that is brand new using the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think not directly. If you add created and updated date columns to your table, you can retrieve them and compare the values; if the record was newly inserted the dates shall be the same, if the record was updated, the dates shall differ. Insert should assign current date as a default value. Update events could fire a trigger to amend the date in the updatedate column